# поиск и сравнение значений в массивах

Tags: php

Вопрос.
Есть два массива.

```
$REP210G = "REP210G.dbf";
$open_db210 = dbase_open($REP210G, 0);
$records = dbase_numrecords($open_db210);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $records; $i++)

{
    $dbf[$i] = dbase_get_record_with_names($open_db210, $i);
    $brr[$i]['lic'] = trim($dbf[$i]['lic']);
    $brr[$i]['add'] = trim($dbf[$i]['add']);
    $brr[$i]['dom'] = trim($dbf[$i]['dom']);
    $brr[$i]['kv']  = trim($dbf[$i]['kv']);

    $lic    = $brr[$i]['lic'];
    $adres  = trim(iconv('CP1251','UTF-8', $brr[$i]['add']));
    $house  = trim(iconv('CP1251','UTF-8', $brr[$i]['dom']));
    $appart = $brr[$i]['kv'];

    $array_210 = array(
            $lic,
            $adres,
            $house,
            $appart
    );
    
    print_r($array_210);
}
```

и

```
$db_novakom = 'novakom.dbf';
$open_db_novakom = dbase_open($db_novakom, 0);
$records_nova = dbase_numrecords($open_db_novakom);
for ($n = 1; $n <= $records_nova; $n++)
{
    $dbf[$n] = dbase_get_record_with_names($open_db_novakom, $n);
    $brr[$n]['NUM']      = trim($dbf[$n]['NUM']);
    $brr[$n]['SUMMA']    = trim($dbf[$n]['SUMMA']);
    $brr[$n]['N_P']      = trim($dbf[$n]['N_P']);
    $brr[$n]['ADATEOPL'] = trim($dbf[$n]['ADATEOPL']);
    $brr[$n]['NAZN']     = trim($dbf[$n]['NAZN']);

    $number = $brr[$n]['NUM'];
    $sum    = $brr[$n]['SUMMA'];
    $descr  = trim(iconv('CP1251','UTF-8', $brr[$n]['N_P']));
    $date   = $brr[$n]['ADATEOPL'];
    $nazn   = $brr[$n]['NAZN'];

    $open_nova = array(
            $number,
            $sum,
            $descr,
            $date,
            $nazn
    );
    
    print_r($open_nova);
}
```

Каким способом можно значение хранящееся в $number из массива $open_db_novakom найти такое же значение $lic в массиве $array_210 и объединив остальные значения переменных вывести на экран?

Иными словами.
Из файла 1.dbf из поля NUM беру строку и ищу значение в файле 2.dbf нахожу и записываю значения в файл out.dbf значения полей из 1.dbf (NUM, SUMMA, N_P, ADATEOPL, NAZN), а из файла 2.dbf найденное значение в NUM из 1.dbf равное значению lic в файле 2.dbf и поля add, dom и kv и все поля из 2х файлов записать в файл out.dbf.
Спасибо.

Comment: я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И проблема в чем?

Comment: И с каким конкретно действием у вас проблема? Вы можете  взять значение, хранящееся в переменной $number из массива $open_db_novakom?

Comment: Хотя массивы, надо признать, очень странные

Comment: Необходимо взять значение, хранящееся в переменной $number из массива $open_db_novakom сравнить это значение со значением, которое хранится в переменой $lic в массиве $array_210 и вывести значения из массива $open_db_novakom ( $number, $sum, $descr,  $date, $nazn ) и вывести найденные значения на экран. Т.е. из массива $array_210 вывести   $lic,
  $adres,
  $house,
  $appart, а из массива $open_db_novakom   $sum,
  $descr,
  $date,
  $nazn. В массив я записываю данные, распарсенные из файлов dbf. Ну и в последствии найденные значения записать в dbf файл. Но это уже следующий вопрос.

Comment: В текущей форме вопрос не имеет смысла. "искать" что-либо можно только в каком-то множестве. А здесь никакого множества не видно. Что находится в переменной $lic? Почему $array_210 одномерный? Что-то искать по значению $lic имеет смысл только в двумерном массиве.

Comment: объединить данные можно через array_merge............... зачем что-то где-то искать - совершенно не ясно......вывести можно через цикл..... а можно просто через `print_r`

Comment: array_merge не подойдёт, поскольку из 2х массивов необходимо выбрать ТОЛЬКО совпадающие переменные. Именно в этом и вопрос - найти совпадающие и записать их в БД.

Comment: Может тогда использовать другой метод, не массивом? Исходники в этой задаче это 2 файла DBF, разной структуры. Разные названия полей.

Comment: вы писали про "совпадение number" а не всех...... так что до сих пор не ясно что вам нужно....совершенно..... лучше бы вы на реальных данных предоставили input и output............  в целом можете смотреть функции работы с массивом...... может `array_intersect`  нужно .

Comment: Более расширенный вопрос. Из файла 1.dbf из поля NUM беру строку и ищу значение в файле 2.dbf нахожу и записываю значения в файл out.dbf значения полей из 1.dbf (NUM, SUMMA, N_P, ADATEOPL, NAZN), а из файла 2.dbf найденное значение в NUM из 1.dbf равное значению lic в файле 2.dbf и поля add, dom и kv и все поля из 2х файлов записать в файл out.dbf.

Comment: Зачем писать код через замочную скважину комментария, если в вашем распоряжении сам вопрос, с возможностью форматировать код?

Comment: Надеюсь так более понятен мой вопрос.